# ngRoute $injector:unpr Unknown Provider

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

Here is my code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'artistControllers'
]);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
  when('/list', {
    templateUrl: 'includes/list.html',
    controller: 'artistListController',
    controllerAs: 'alc',
  }).
  when('/detail/:id', {
    templateUrl: 'includes/detail.html',
    controller: 'artistDetailController',
    controllerAs: 'adc',
  }).
  otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/list'
  });
}]);
```

My index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Angular Demo</title>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular-animate.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script> //include artistListController and artistDetailController
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="main" ng-view></div>
</body>

</html>
```

If I use `angular-route.min.js` v1.4.3, it will throw `$injector:unpr Unknown Provider` and the url is stuck on http://127.0.0.1:56116/index.html

`angular-route.min.js` v1.2.10 works fine and the url is http://127.0.0.1:56116/index.html/#list

Anybody can help me with this? Thank you

Comment: `artistControllers` - what module is this and is this defined as well as is its script included?

Comment: i believe artistControllers should not be there with ngRoute.

Comment: @callmekatootie: it is my own controller. It is included in my index.html

Comment: @atinder: I tried to remove it, but the problem is still the same

Comment: @LongTran Your AngularJS and Angular Route (and any other angular related libraries) should be of the same version. Are they? When you use Angular Route 1.4.3, make sure that Angular is also version 1.4.3

Comment: @callmekatootie: oh damn, my bad. I download the 1.4.3 Angular Route version, but I copied the old version of Angular (1.2.9). Sorry for this damn stupid question

Answer (score 0):

This error results from the $injector being unable to resolve a required dependency. To fix this, make sure the dependency is defined and spelled correctly.
Removing `artistControllers` from your `angular.module` will solve the problem.Also include `artistListController` and `artistDetailController` in your index.html file.

Answer (score 0):

including all the controller in your index.html like this:

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/artistListController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/artistDetailController.js"></script>
</body>
```

In your app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
  when('/list', {
    templateUrl: 'includes/list.html',
    controller: 'artistListController'
  }).
  when('/detail/:id', {
    templateUrl: 'includes/detail.html',
    controller: 'artistDetailController'
  }).
  otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/list'
  });
}]);
```

Comment: Yes I did include them. I think the problem is not that I forgot to include it